# Workflow does not finish when initiated by dictation command

Tags: applescript

I created the following script to open up the dictation commands editor in system preferences. It works when I run it from within automator, but when I use a dictation command to initiate the workflow, it gets stuck after revealing the "Accessibility" pane. Any ideas?

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane "Accessibility"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    delay 1
    select table 1 of scroll area 2 of window 1
    delay 1
    select row 14 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of window 1
    delay 0.5
    click button 2 of window 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to give permission to "Dictation" setting under to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility to get this to work.